# UIImagePickerController shows only Videos folder but not others like Selfies and Slo-mo

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When using `UIImagePickerController`, I can filter videos only to display iOS 12 (also applies to iOS 10+) using the codes below:

```
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   picker.videoExportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
}
present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, a lot of iOS default folders are displayed, such as Moments, Camera Roll, Recently Added, Videos, Selfies, Slo-mo and other albums I created.

How can I just display the **Videos** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` as source type. It will show all videos only.

```swift
picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
```

Also instead of using string for media types better use constant:

```swift
import MobileCoreServices
...
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
```

Comment: by choosing `.savedPhotosAlbum`, it only displays "Moments" album (like the Photos App > Photo tab), which is sorted by date and location of video taken. Yet the layout is not 4-in-a-row (the one used in Photos app > Album tab). How can I make it the layout the same as the 4-in-a-row? The latter constant suggestion doesn't have any differences at all.

Comment: There is no way currently to open specific album (like 4-in-row video). You can only choose among three options: `camera`, `photoLibrary` or `savedPhotosAlbum `. If you want such layout you need to implement ImagePicker by yourself or choose among existing pods.